# XMLSpy: how does a Complex Type relate to the file it references?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm brand new to XML/XSD, so I may not be asking the question in the right way...

In XMLSpy (and perhaps XSD in general), how do I determine/specify the link between a Complex Type (e.g., BusinessUnitType) and the file that defines that Complex Type (e.g,. FCLBusinessUnitTypeV1_00_00.xsd)?

I can see all the files that are referenced, via include or import, in the Schema Overview, but I'm not clear on what/how the files are linked to the Complex Types that reference them.

For example, a snippet of an XSD:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="FCLBusinessUnitTypeV1_00_00.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="BusinessUnit" type="eai:BusinessUnitType"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Think of **[xsd:include](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#compound-schema)** as bringing in the declarations of the referenced XSD into the current XSD.  Then, referencing from `@type` attributes takes place as it would had those declarations originally appeared in the XSD.

If the namespace of the referenced XSD differs from that of the current XSD, then use **[xsd:import](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#composition-schemaImport)**.

Comment: What I meant was: how do I know that a file i include or import corresponds to a Complex Type in the XSD diagram (denoted by dashed line)? As in the example above: how do I know that the element of type "BusinessUnitType" links to (i.e., is defined in) the file "FCLBusinessUnitTypeV1_00_00.xsd"? Thx

Comment: Given your comment, I now understand that your question is more particular to XMLSpy than I thought.  I've rolled back my edit of your question.   Sorry.  I do not know the answer to your XMLSpy-particular question.

Comment: Understood, but... I think (with my limited understanding) that my question applies equally in the general sense: looking at an XSD file (with a plain text editor), how can I tell that a Complex Type (as above "BusinessUnitType") is defined in the file "FCLBusinessUnitTypeV1_00_00.xsd"? All I see in the declaration section is a bunch of imports and includes, and down in the main section

Comment: (continuing from previous) ... some Complex Types magically make reference to the files. I don't know where to see how that link is done. Thx

Comment: Ok, now I'm back to thinking maybe you *are* looking for a general explanation of the sort I tried to provide in this answer.  Just looking at a `@type` attribute, you cannot be sure in which file the referenced type resides.   Typically, however, you can guess based on the name or the namespace if reasonable naming practices were used.  But, you're right, nothing in XSD directly will tell you in the general case the file from which a declaration originated if naming and namespace clues don't help.